# HTTP output in Logstash with JSON (to teams webhook)

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, logstash, elk

I want to use logstash to read files and send messages to teams webhook, but the console says

```
[2023-06-28T10:04:05,828][ERROR][logstash.outputs.http][main][a426c749e290f2ae6144df4f0d2c91d791cf4273431bcb4fffb17f1f69460f74] [HTTP Output Failure] En countered non-2xx HTTP code 400 {:response_code=>400, :url=> "https://elsgre.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/xx", :event=>#<LogStash::Event:0x6cfcf570>}
```

But it works for me with POSTMAN or curl

```
curl -X POST \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
      -d '{"text": "postman test2"}' \
      "https://elsgre.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/xx"
```

The following is my output

```
input {
   file {
     path => "/opt/testLog/test.log"
     sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
     start_position => "beginning"
     mode => "read"
     file_completed_action => "log"
     file_completed_log_path => "/tmp/logstash-completed.log"
     codec => plain { charset => "UTF-8" }
     tags => ["logstash-file-input"]
   }
}

filter {
}

output {
   http {
     url => "https://elsgre.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/xx"
     http_method => "post"
     format => "json"
     content_type => "application/json"
     message => '{"text": "postman test2"}'
   }
}
```

This is the message from --debug console

```
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@format = "json"
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@http_method = "post"
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@id = "xxxxx"
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@content_type = "application/json"
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@message = "{\"text\": \"postman test2\"}"
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@url = "https://elsgre.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/xx"
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@enable_metric = true
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@codec = <LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_4be9fafa-86ac-4d87-8ba2-b5b24252c424", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@workers = 1
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@request_timeout = 60
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@socket_timeout = 10
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@connect_timeout = 10
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@follow_redirects = true
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@pool_max = 50
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@pool_max_per_route = 25
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@keepalive = true
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@automatic_retries = 1
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@retry_non_idempotent = false
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@validate_after_inactivity = 200
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@keystore_type = "JKS"
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@truststore_type = "JKS"
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@cookies = true
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@headers = {}
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@retry_failed = true
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@retryable_codes = [429, 500, 502, 503, 504]
config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@http_compression = false
```

This is the message from --debug console

Comment: Can you run logstash with `--debug` to see if there's more debugging output around the call?

Comment: Yes, but there are too many words for debug, which paragraph do you need me to confirm?

Comment: Anything from `logstash.outputs.http`